# ODI 11g upgrade hangs on 54%

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I am having a problem on upgrading ODI 10g to ODI 11.1.1.9. It hangs on 54%.

The Master Repository were upgraded just fine, but when it come down to the Work Repository, it just hung.

It did all the upgrade on the repository Structure but hung on the Repository Data.

see log below:

```
ODI Work Repository Upgrade: Upgrading Repository Structure...
Applying DDL from file C:\oracle\product\11.1.1\Oracle_ODI_1\oracledi.sdk\lib\scripts\ORACLE\patches\E_04.02.02.01_04.02.03.01.xml
Applying DDL from file C:\oracle\product\11.1.1\Oracle_ODI_1\oracledi.sdk\lib\scripts\ORACLE\patches\E_04.02.03.01_04.03.01.01.xml
Applying DDL from file C:\oracle\product\11.1.1\Oracle_ODI_1\oracledi.sdk\lib\scripts\ORACLE\patches\E_04.03.01.01_04.03.02.01.xml
Applying DDL from file C:\oracle\product\11.1.1\Oracle_ODI_1\oracledi.sdk\lib\scripts\ORACLE\patches\E_04.03.02.01_04.03.02.02.xml
Applying DDL from file C:\oracle\product\11.1.1\Oracle_ODI_1\oracledi.sdk\lib\scripts\ORACLE\patches\E_04.03.02.02_04.03.02.03.xml
Applying DDL from file C:\oracle\product\11.1.1\Oracle_ODI_1\oracledi.sdk\lib\scripts\ORACLE\patches\E_04.03.02.03_04.03.02.04.xml
Applying DDL from file C:\oracle\product\11.1.1\Oracle_ODI_1\oracledi.sdk\lib\scripts\ORACLE\patches\E_04.03.02.04_04.03.03.01.xml
Applying DDL from file C:\oracle\product\11.1.1\Oracle_ODI_1\oracledi.sdk\lib\scripts\ORACLE\patches\E_04.03.03.01_04.03.03.02.xml
Applying DDL from file C:\oracle\product\11.1.1\Oracle_ODI_1\oracledi.sdk\lib\scripts\ORACLE\patches\W_04.02.02.01_04.02.03.01.xml
Applying DDL from file C:\oracle\product\11.1.1\Oracle_ODI_1\oracledi.sdk\lib\scripts\ORACLE\patches\W_04.02.03.01_04.03.01.01.xml
Applying DDL from file C:\oracle\product\11.1.1\Oracle_ODI_1\oracledi.sdk\lib\scripts\ORACLE\patches\W_04.03.01.01_04.03.02.01.xml
Applying DDL from file C:\oracle\product\11.1.1\Oracle_ODI_1\oracledi.sdk\lib\scripts\ORACLE\patches\W_04.03.02.01_04.03.02.02.xml
Applying DDL from file C:\oracle\product\11.1.1\Oracle_ODI_1\oracledi.sdk\lib\scripts\ORACLE\patches\W_04.03.02.02_04.03.02.03.xml
Applying DDL from file C:\oracle\product\11.1.1\Oracle_ODI_1\oracledi.sdk\lib\scripts\ORACLE\patches\W_04.03.02.03_04.03.02.04.xml
Applying DDL from file C:\oracle\product\11.1.1\Oracle_ODI_1\oracledi.sdk\lib\scripts\ORACLE\patches\W_04.03.02.04_04.03.03.01.xml
Applying DDL from file C:\oracle\product\11.1.1\Oracle_ODI_1\oracledi.sdk\lib\scripts\ORACLE\patches\W_04.03.03.01_04.03.03.02.xml
ODI Work Repository Upgrade: Upgrading Repository Data...
```

And here it is till now. There is no error message anywhere and I have no idea what should I do.

The server is a Windows Server 2008 - x64

May someone help me??

thank you a lot

Comment: I haven't used ODI, but some Oracle product upgrades can be debugged like any other slow process, by looking at slow SQL statements.  I'd start with a query like this to see what's running right now: `select elapsed_time/1000000 seconds, v$sql.* from v$sql where users_executing > 0 order by seconds desc;`.

Answer (score 0):

Run first Rcc then solve fatals and severes errors.

All will go fine after.